# Youtube API channel search - how to get channel ids by using video ids

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube API for a simple search for music in a specific genre. In the results set I get only videos ids and the part with channel ids is empty. Is there any way to generate/get the channel ids from the retrieved videos?

I have tried to look only for channels, but the result set is either completely emtpy or contains 1-2 results.

```
youtube.search().list(q = query,
                      part = "id",                                         
                      #type = 'channel, video',
                      maxResults = max_results).execute()
```

I would like to get both videos and channel ids and currently I am receiving only a list of videos that match with the search query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just request the 'snippet' part as well. The snippet section contains the channelId of the video.